# Angular Material Toolbar replace div when space runs out

Tags: css, angular-material, toolbar

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the toolbar in this:
https://preview.themeforest.net/item/angular-landing-material-design-angular-app-landing-page/full_screen_preview/21198258

In the an Angular Material Toolbar component. You'll notice that when you change the window width the toolbar content goes from centred to full width and when the content that is not the logo gets to big it disappears and is replaced with the right hand burger menu.

Can anyone please give me a working example?

Comment: Probably using css media queries

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly seems to be the issue with your solution?